# UWP TreeView - Update of data behind a binding makes the Expandable icon to disappear

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, treeview, uwp-xaml

With a TreeView I have a Patient structure:

```
        private ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz> _Patients;

        public ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz> Patients
        {
            get { return _Patients; }
            private set { Set(ref _Patients, value); }
        }
```

and a treeView bound to it:

```
            <winui:TreeView
                x:Name="treeView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Expanding="treeView_Expanding"
                ItemInvoked="OnItemInvoked"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Patients, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectionMode="Single" />
```

with Item Template:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewBase">
            <winui:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">
                <controls1:TreeViewControl Data="{x:Bind}" />
            </winui:TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and CustomControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TitoDoc2020.Views.TreeViewControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TitoDoc2020.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="using:TitoDoc2020.Models"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="PAZTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewPaz">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <FontIcon
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="&#xE77B;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="VisitTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewVisit">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <FontIcon
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                    Foreground="{x:Bind ImageColor}"
                    Glyph="{x:Bind ImageSrc}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind VisitDescr}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I have then 4 AppBarTogleButton to select the sorting order of the Patients.
Each of them invoke the same procedure:

```
        private async void AppBarToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sorting = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.ReadAsync<string>("TreeViewSort");

            switch (((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarToggleButton)sender).Name)
            {
                case "DescDate":
                    if (sorting == "DescDate")
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    AsceDate.IsChecked = false;
                    AsceAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    DescAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                case "AsceDate":
                    if (sorting == "AsceDate")
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    DescDate.IsChecked = false;
                    AsceAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    DescAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                case "DescAlph":
                    if (sorting == "DescAlph")
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    AsceDate.IsChecked = false;
                    DescDate.IsChecked = false;
                    AsceAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                case "AsceAlph":
                    if (sorting == "AsceAlph")
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    AsceDate.IsChecked = false;
                    DescDate.IsChecked = false;
                    DescAlph.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.SaveAsync("TreeViewSort", ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarToggleButton)sender).Name);
            _sorting = ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarToggleButton)sender).Name;
            await SortTreeAsync(false);
        }
```

and in the SortTreeAsync:

```
        private async Task SortTreeAsync(bool setCheck)
        {
            ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz> _patients;

            if (treeView.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                return;
            }
            treeView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            switch (_sorting)
            {
                case "DescDate":
                    if (setCheck) DescDate.IsChecked = true;
                    Patients = new ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz>(
                        from i in Patients orderby i.Data descending, i.Cognome, i.Nome select i);
/*                    await treeView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                       {
                           Patients = _patients;
                       });
 */
                    break;
                case "AsceDate":
                    if (setCheck) AsceDate.IsChecked = true;
                    Patients = new ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz>(
                        from i in Patients orderby i.Data, i.Cognome, i.Nome select i);
                    break;
                case "DescAlph":
                    if (setCheck) DescAlph.IsChecked = true;
                    Patients = new ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz>(
                        from i in Patients orderby i.Cognome descending, i.Nome descending, i.Data descending select i);
                    break;
                case "AsceAlph":
                    if (setCheck) AsceAlph.IsChecked = true;
                    Patients = new ObservableCollection<MTreeViewPaz>(
                        from i in Patients orderby i.Cognome, i.Nome, i.Data descending select i);
                    break;
                default:
                    DescDate.IsChecked = true;
                    break;
            }
            treeView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            return;
        }
```

I update the Patients with the new sorted one. 
The issue is that after I change the sorting order couple of time the > to expand the leafs disapper:
[image: Correct with leafs]

[image: WRONG - no leaf sign]

I've checked and the data structure is absolutely identical (apart from the order) and correct

How is this possible?

--- Additional info ---

[image: Before sorting]

[image: This is the breakpoint after the sorting]

[image: After sorting]

As you can see the child structure is still there

Comment: If TreeViewItem `ItemsSource` property is empty, it will has no arrow icon. please check the if datasource contains sub array after re-order.

Comment: I've added the screenshots on the list before and after the sorting. The data is ok, but there are no arrow icons.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT sorry it does not work :( I've provided more details below. If you want I can share with you the project

Comment: Any update on this? were you able to repro with the new code and db?

Answer (score 0):

> UWP TreeView - Update of data behind a binding makes the Expandable icon to disappear

Please check this line  `<winui:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">`, you used `x:Bind` OneTime model that will not response `Visits` property changed, please edit it with **OneWay** or **TwoWay** model and **please sure you have call OnPropertyChanged event for `Visits` property**.

`<winui:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits, Mode=OneWay}">`

Comment: I've added `x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay"` in the page and in the TreeView as well as in the item custom Control but the effect is the same :(
            <winui:TreeView
                x:Name="treeView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay"
                Expanding="treeView_Expanding"
                ItemInvoked="OnItemInvoked"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Patients}"
                SelectionMode="Single" />
        </Grid>

Comment: <DataTemplate
            x:Key="ItemTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewBase"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <winui:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">
                <controls1:TreeViewControl Data="{x:Bind}" />
            </winui:TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: Please share mini complete project for me . I will edit base on your demo.

Comment: here is the link project and test database. You should import in SQLEXPRESS. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohVtHaw3aCiwaE8ADrS0bbIbs6vkA?e=FqRZXi

Comment: Cool, I will test it.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need any info... and thank you for the help!

Comment: were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried your code sample but it throw sql exception, we could not reproduce this with you sample.

Comment: In order for it to work you have to install SQLExpress and enable its TCP/IP and browser as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases 
Then you have to restore the db backup I provided so you have the db matching the EF model
otherwise can you tell me which is the exception? I can try to understand what's not working.

Comment: the default connection string is: Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TitoDoc_Test;Integrated Security=True;User ID=;
so if you restore the DB with the name "TitoDoc_Test" it should connect correctly

Comment: I eidt the sample with above but It still can't work.

Comment: I've updated the code in the folder and added a video where I do everything in a virtual machine. Started from scratch I do restore the DB, compile the app, execute it, and show the issue. Thank you for your patience and help! I'm really stuck!

Comment: I saw your video, but for security reason we can't deploy your server in my current environment, sorry guys.

Comment: Nico, help me understand what I can do to help as the issue is still there and continues not to work and dead blocking me. Do you want me to provide you the SQL scripts (table and view creation) and sample data creation? so that is not a DB restore?

Comment: In my opinion, this is treeview 's bug, the better way is report it in [WinUI](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) GitHub issue box.