# UWP XAML TreeView with Data Binding: nested items vanish

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

When using a  with Data Binding to my tree, the items are shown nicely, until a change is made to the tree contents. Then, nested items tend to vanish.

I have tried [UWP TreeView - Update of data behind a binding makes the Expandable icon to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330158/uwp-treeview-update-of-data-behind-a-binding-makes-the-expandable-icon-to-disa), which does not fix the issue. (essentially using x:Bind, Mode=OneWay).

I have also tried to use a club and just call a PropertyChanged for the tree base, to basically force the update of the whole tree. Also, sub-items vanish. Virtualization

Any help? This issue has been there for what appears to be at least 7 years... Staring down the road of custom ListView.

Comment: "until a change is made to the tree contents" Could you please provide detailed code snippets to illustrate this change? I tested the Treeview and changed the data in the collection, and I did not reproduce your behavior.

Comment: Hi Junjie, it looks like it's the version of the component that shipped with the Win10 build. Switching to the W11 build, this behavior is gone. Since I need to work on W10, I'll just quickly whip up a custom design to extend ListView to do what I need to get done reliably. Thank you for your help.